# Bulk import data via LogStash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have to bulk import data via LogStash as below :

Source: Restful Get APIs

Destination : ElasticSearch

My logstash config file looks as below:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
     test1 => {
       method => get
       url => "https://forun/questions?limit=100&offset=0"
       headers => {
         Accept => "application/json"
    }
  }
}

output {
elasticsearch{
 hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 index => "testindex"
}
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

This fetches 200 records at a time.

But, I have more than 10000 records and need to apply pagination logic in input of http-poller plugin.

Please help how can I apply pagination logic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right architecture. Why have you decided to pull data into Logstash (using the http_poller input plugin) instead of pushing data to Logstash?

If it's a single bulk upload; you could just script something to send events directly to Logstash over http (using http input plugin). Alternatively if it's not a single bulk upload and there's a lot of data that grows over time, you might consider sending events to something like Kafka/Redis/RabbitMQ, which can get streamed to Logstash using associated input plugins.

Comment: My bad! I am actually using logstash pipeline to push data to ElasticSearch

Comment: ok, why are you using the http_poller plugin then? Wouldn't http plugin be more appropriate...

Comment: Using http_poller plugin I am calling an HTTP API, decode the output, filter it as per need, and send data to ES.

Comment: Just went through logstash-input-http. I think it will be more suitable for my requirement. Thanks a ton for suggesting Ryan. Appreciate it!

Comment: Let me phrase this a bit differently. Why not have something send data to Logstash, instead of having Logstash polling and fetching data from an API

Comment: Apologies, you're previous comment came in while I was writing. Thanks - don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: Yeah! I totally agree to that. Will leverage the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I want to load bulk data into elasticsearch using http_poller input plugin.
The data is fetched from sap CDC and hence needs user and password in the request. How can I achieve this using HTTP input plugin as http_poller only allows 300 records and even in subsequent runs it pulls random data instead f incremental load.
This is my implementation of http_poller. how can I d the same using HTTP input plugin?

````
input {
http_poller {
  urls => {
    test_url =>{
      url => "${cdcurl}"
      method => post
      user => "${devuser}"
      password => "${password}"
      headers => {
                "Accept" => "application/json"
              }
      params => {
          query => "select * from accounts where created >= '2022-09-17T15:00:00.010Z'"
        }
      }
  }
  codec => "json"
  request_timeout => 60
  schedule => { "every" => "20s" }
}
}

filter {
 json {
    source => "message"
  }
  split {
    field => "[results]"
  }
  prune {
        whitelist_names => ["^results$"]
      }
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
        cloud_id => '${ELASTICSEARCH_CLOUD_ID}'
        cloud_auth => '${ELASTICSEARCH_CLOUD_AUTH}'
        index => "sapcdc"
        action => "index"
        document_id => "%{[results][UID]}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}```
````